# m2eclipse "Resolve in workspace" but in IntelliJ? Possible?

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to make IntelliJ choose a Maven module in my Intellij Project over the module in the repository, but I can't get it to work!
I am trying to do what is called "Resolve in workspace" in Eclipse... anyone who knows how to do this in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the comments in [this bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-25146) discussion.

Comment: I'd be nice to paraphrase the specific solution, a link to a long thread seems quite messy.